# How to say this properly in English

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

In our area, we have a common saying that,

**"Failure may make you feel bad, but humiliation is what make you work hard**"
*(Sorry for my bad English translation)*

Does English have any proper saying for the above example like proverb or something?

If not, please suggest me a better way to say that.

The above sentence is like my motto. So I want to say it proper and keep it. So your help will be extremely helpful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing directly the same.  The only one I can think that comes close is:

> If at first you don't succeed: try, try again!

There are several hundred quotes from famous people on the subject, though (some more famous than others).  For example:

> "It's fine to celebrate success but it is more important to heed the lessons of failure" - Bill Gates
>
> "Success is not final, failure is not fatal: it is the courage to continue that counts." (usually wrongly attributed to Winston Churchill)
>
> "Success consists of going from failure to failure without loss of enthusiasm" (usually wrongly attributed to Winston Churchill)
>
> "If you learn from defeat, you haven't really lost" - Zig Ziglar
>
> "Winning isn't everything -- it's the *only* thing" - Red Sanders (but often wrongly attributed to Vince Lombardi)

This doesn't mean you can't say this cleverly in English. I'll have to make something up, though.  How about:

> Failure is painful, but there is no motivation like humiliation

Or more generic:

> There is no motivation like humiliation

Comment: Your examples are all good. Thank you so much. It seems there is no quote available. Is my sentence good? Can u suggest a better / shorter way to say that?

Comment: There may be a quote from a famous person that says something very similar, but there is no *common* English expression.  How about **"Failure is painful, but there is no motivation like humiliation"**

Comment: This one is better Andrew. Thank you so much. I'm really satisfied with this quote.

Comment: If you add the above in your answer, I will up vote it and make the question "answered".

Comment: @Raj33  edited my answer.